# matplotlib remove unexpected extra row and large padding around plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have been trying to create an image with 7 heatmaps subplots with matplotlib and seaborn. Here's what i tried:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 15

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=4, nrows=2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 2])

idx = 0
for hpp in hands_percentages_positions:
    idx += 1
    sns.heatmap(
            hpp,
            cbar=False,
            cmap="YlGnBu",
            square=True,
            annot=myMat,
            annot_kws={"size": 7},
            fmt='',
            xticklabels=False,
            yticklabels=False,
            ax=eval('ax'+str(idx)))

plt.savefig('./myplots.png')
```

Which produce the following image, I have drawn in **pink** and **red** what I don't want:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `plt.savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)`. As you create square heatmaps, your subplots also should be close to square.  As in `rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 8`

Comment: There is no extra row.  As the subplots are forced to be square, their heigth must be reduced in a 15x15 figure . You need a different figsize.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem.