# Matplotlib animation shows only a part of each figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I create a chain of figures and save them into an animation.

My problem is that the image of the figure that I see on the screen is *different* from what is saved by [`savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).
This problem is saved by passing `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1` to `savefig` as recommended in a comment to [matplotlib remove unexpected extra row and large padding around plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66401302/850781).

However, [`FuncAnimation.save`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) does not accept those arguments, so the saved movie has an incorrect bounding box.

What do I do?